# Табы с изменением url

Tags: javascript

Народ, подскажите, где почитать про табы, имеющие возможность изменять адрес в строке.

Comment: @cevil_cevil, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут посмотреть: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAjAUmtGylY